# On key press - not working in Chrome mobile (Android)?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome on Android (8.0.0), and `onkeypress` is not catching edit events on the `contenteditable` `div`.

```html
<div contenteditable ='true' onkeypress =alert("press")> When ediiting this text, you should get an alert. Does not work on Android chrome. </div>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `onkeydown()`.

```html
<div contenteditable='true' onkeydown=alert("press")>Text</div>
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't return false to prevent user input

Comment: @DavidSomekh Sorry, edited my answer. Try with `onkeydown()`.

Comment: It's catching the event, but returning false does not prevent the user from inserting text. Any idea?